# Cannot import contacts by using ImportContactsRequest

Tags: telethon

I'm facing a problem that when I request to import contacts, it returns PopularContact with no information, even that Telegram account already added my account, and this is return result

```
ImportedContacts(
        imported=[
        ],
        popular_invites=[
                PopularContact(
                        client_id=0,
                        importers=208
                ),
        ],
        retry_contacts=[
        ],
        users=[
        ]
)
```

When I add other normal phone numbers, it still works

```
ImportedContacts(
        imported=[
                ImportedContact(
                        user_id=xxxxxxx,
                        client_id=10000000
                ),
        ],
        popular_invites=[
        ],
        retry_contacts=[
        ],
        users=[
                User(
                        id=xxxxxxx,
                        is_self=False,
                        contact=True,
                        mutual_contact=False,
                        deleted=False,
                        bot=False,
                        bot_chat_history=False,
                        bot_nochats=False,
                        verified=False,
                        restricted=False,
                        min=False,
                        bot_inline_geo=False,
                        support=False,
                        scam=False,
               )
       ]
)
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
        contacts=[types.InputPhoneContact(
            client_id=random.randrange(-2**63, 2**63),
            phone='some string here',
            first_name='some string here',
            last_name='some string here'
        )]
    ))
    print(result.stringify()
```

[read docs](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/import_contacts.html)